# Pass items found on resolve.path with browserify through transforms

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, browserify

Using `paths` option to browserify, as discussed here: [How do I manage relative path aliasing in multiple grunt-browserify bundles?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23608416/19212), it seems that the files included over the path are not passed through the `coffee` transform.

I.e. with

```
var b = browserify('./app', {paths: ['./node_modules','./src/js']});
```

And somewhere in your code

```
require('x.coffee')
```

Even though `package.json` includes e.g. `browserify: {"transform": ["coffeeify"]}` and correctly transforms any source code found relative to the root (i.e. not by way of the `paths` argument).

If `x.coffee` is found in `./src/js` then Browserify will throw an error, probably `Unexpected string` or some other parsing issue.

Can one pass items found by way of the `paths` through the `coffee` transform?

***Edit*** May be related to https://github.com/jnordberg/coffeeify/issues/10#issuecomment-39624824 and https://github.com/substack/module-deps/issues/33

I would also add that I have tried many variations of `global: true` and `globalTransforms: ['coffeeify']`, to no success as of yet.

I have also tried adding a `package.json` to the `./src/js` directory with variations of `"browserify": {"transform":["coffeeify"]}`, and browserify certainly seems to read the `package.json`, as it errors when the file is malformed, but it does not seem to respect the `browserify` options specified there.