# Browserify paths and Webstorm configuration

Tags: javascript, npm, webstorm, browserify

I build my project with gulp and use browserify.
To make path resolution easier i [configurated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158401/how-do-i-manage-relative-path-aliasing-in-multiple-grunt-browserify-bundles) browserify

```
var b = browserify('./app', {paths: ['./node_modules','./src/js']});
```

The problem is that WebStorm IDE don't know about this and doesn't help me with intellisense when i require files. For example intellisense does't work on the following line

```
var Store = require('lib/account/stores/account-store');
```

Is there any way i can make Webstorm IDE aware of my paths settings?

Comment: I have a similiar issue with WebStorm and the resolution of classnames, didnt fix it yet, as it only affects one lib though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by using symlinks.
Followed the advice from this link
https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#organizing-modules

> symlink
>
> The simplest thing you can do is to symlink your app root directory
>   into your node_modules/ directory.
>
> Did you know that symlinks work on windows too?
>
> To link a lib/ directory in your project root into node_modules, do:
>
> ln -s ../lib node_modules/app and now from anywhere in your project
>   you'll be able to require files in lib/ by doing require('app/foo.js')
>   to get lib/foo.js.

Comment: This is not a good answer - please elaborate exactly how you used symlinks to achieve this.  Also did the original answer not solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer.  It's much clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can do this. Even the standard RequireJS [baseUrl](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-baseUrl) is not yet honored - see [WEB-13463](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13463). And you can hardly expect the IDE to recognize the tricks added by certain gulp/grunt tasks.

WebStorm allows marking folders as 'Resource roots' - folders marked this way are treated as root folders, so that paths are resolved relative to them. But this only works for 'absolute' URLs (with leading slash - `'/lib/account/stores/account-store'`, but not `'lib/account/stores/account-store'`)