# ECMAScript 6 - Base import path?

Tags: node.js, browserify

I am programming in ES6 using babelify and browserify. To keep my code clean, I want the **import** tag to be at a specific path, no matter which folder you're in.

For example, if I was in /, and I wrote this:

```
import foo from "foo/Foo.js";
```

It would be the same as if I wrote that line in any other folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: Where do you want it to load `foo/Foo.js` from?

Comment: Well, in the program, I only have 1 javascript file not in any folder, and all the other files in their own respective folder. So I guess relative to the 1 javascript file not in any folder.

Comment: Is there some reason that `../Foo.js` won't work?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ES6 or Babel. ES6 doesn't make any assumptions about what the module identifier represents (i.e. it doesn't even know that it is a file path). Please see https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/767  and http://stackoverflow.com/q/20158401/218196 and tons of similar questions.

Comment: @torazuburo I just don't like how it looks, which is why I want to keep the code clean and set a base import path

Comment: @FelixKling I just put those tags because they were relevant to my question